# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Django template throwing the following error processing a pandas data frame .

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 's_results.iterrows()'

views.py

```
return render(request,'search.html',{'s_results':s_results})
```

search.html

```
{% for index, row in s_results.iterrows() %} <li>  {{ row['ColName'] }}</li>  {% endfor %}
```

Can I get some help ?

Comment: Answer depending on what s_results is (Pandas dataframe?) but most likelly you need tchange iterator to this `{% for index, row in s_results.iterrows %}`

Comment: Thanks . That helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put this as an answer to allow you accept it and close the question: you need tchange iterator to this `{% for index, row in s_results.iterrows %}`